# Estilização de controladores de video

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estou querendo estilizar os controladores que criei com HTML, CSS e JavaScript, porem não estou conseguindo fazer um que seria o de "mutar" (retirar o som). Ele funciona da seguinte maneira: irá ter a imagem de uma nota musical que significa que o som está inativo e quando clicar em cima dela terá que ficar com a mesma imagem, porem com um risco que indica que o som esta ativo. Esse e o código que usei para faze eles:

O HTML:

```
<section id="header">
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="video">
                    <img src="images/bg-video.png" id="bg-video">
                    <!--                     poster="images/batimento.jpg"-->
                    <video id="Video1" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop>
                        <source src="video/animacao-lol.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>

                <h1 class="nomes">Lorem ipsum <strong class="slidText">Dolor</strong></h1>
                <p class="texto1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque. <br>Cras sit amet ligula 
                    ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>


                <div id="buttonbar" style="display: none;">

                    <button id="play" title="Play button"></button>
                    <button id="volDn"  title="Volume down button">-</button>
                    <button id="volUp"  title="Volume up button">+</button>
                    <button id="mute" title="Mute button" ><img src="images/video/demultado.png"/></button>        
                </div>   

                <center>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="#one" class="botao-circulo scrolly"><img src="images/seta-baixo.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </center>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Criei algumas `divs` na minha estrutura para poder estilizar os botões com o CSS:

```
#buttonbar #play{
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
}
#buttonbar #volDn{
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
#buttonbar #volUp{
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}

#buttonbar #mute{
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:6px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(0.3);
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
#buttonbar img{
  transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

E por fim tem o JavaScript que da ação aos meus botões, porem em um deles que seria no botão `mute` a duas imagens sendo setadas via JavaScript que seria aquela forma que expliquei no começo do tópico. Mas não sei como estilizar aquilo e muito menos setar a hierarquia de pastas que se encontra a minha imagem. Segue o print da minha estrutura onde se encontra as imagens e o código JavaScript:

[image: Código JavaScript]

As minhas duas imagens estão dentro da pasta vídeo:

O código JavaScript:

```
function init() {        // Master function, encapsulates all functions
    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
    if (video.canPlayType) {   // tests that we have HTML5 video support
        // if successful, display buttons and set up events
        document.getElementById("buttonbar").style.display = "block";



        //  play video
        function vidplay(evt) {
            if (video.src == "") {  // inital source load
                getVideo();
            }
            button = evt.target; //  get the button id to swap the text based on the state                                    
            if (video.paused) {   // play the file, and display pause symbol
                video.play();
                button.textContent = "||";
            } else {              // pause the file, and display play symbol  
                video.pause();
                button.textContent = ">";
            }
        }



        // change volume based on incoming value 
        function setVol(value) {
            var vol = video.volume;
            vol += value;
            //  test for range 0 - 1 to avoid exceptions
            if (vol >= 0 && vol <= 1) {
                // if valid value, use it
                video.volume = vol;
            } else {
                // otherwise substitute a 0 or 1
                video.volume = (vol < 0) ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }


        //  button events               
        //  Play


        document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", vidplay, false);

        // volume buttons
        document.getElementById("volDn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            setVol(-.1); // down by 10%
        }, false);
        document.getElementById("volUp").addEventListener("click", function () {
            setVol(.1);  // up by 10%
        }, false);


        document.getElementById("mute").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            if (video.muted) {
                video.muted = false;
                evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume on button' src='../images/video/mutado.png' id='js-imagem' />"
            } else {
                video.muted = true;
                evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume off button' src='../images/video/desmutado.png' />"
            }
        }, false);
    } // end of runtime
}// end of master
```